# Merge sublist with each item of list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of lists and I need to join them together with each item of list. See example below:

```
my_list = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Expected result:

```
['1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.2.4', '1.2.5', '1.3.4', '1.3.5']
```

I tried to write the logic but one or other items are always missing.

Comment: Show your code as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of *strings* as result? Because what you have shown as expected result is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: Yes, output should be a string for each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate, product

# ensure sub-items are lists
def as_lst(x):
    return x if isinstance(x, list) else [str(x)]

out = [str(e) for l in (accumulate(map(as_lst, my_list),
                                   lambda *x: ['.'.join(map(str, y))
                                               for y in product(*x)])
                       )
       for e in as_lst(l)]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
['1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.2.4', '1.2.5', '1.3.4', '1.3.5']
```

Output for `my_list=[[1,2],3,[4,5]]`:

```
['1', '2', '1.3', '2.3', '1.3.4', '1.3.5', '2.3.4', '2.3.5']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def join_lists(result, prefix, items):
    if not items:
        result.append('.'.join(map(str, prefix)))
    else:
        for i, item in enumerate(items[0]):
            join_lists(result, prefix + [item], items[1:])
        join_lists(result, prefix, items[1:])

my_list = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5]]
result = []
join_lists(result, [1], my_list)
print(result)
```

will produce:

`Output: ['1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.2.4', '1.2.5', '1.3.4', '1.3.5']`

Comment: Thanks. One issue, You added 1 as prefix however that will not always be the case even the first item can be sublist. basically the logic should looks for the all items in the list and combine them.

even the 2nd or other items in the list in guaranteed to be a sublist it can be a item or list.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import itertools
my_list = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5]]

# First convert each scalar into list 
my_list = [[e] if not isinstance(e, list) else e for e in my_list]

# and then each element into str
my_list = [list(map(str, e)) for e in my_list]

# Then initialize a result list and keep extending with product of the result 
# with the next element in my_list
t = my_list[0]
out = []
out.extend(t)
for lst in my_list[1:]:
    t = list(map('.'.join, itertools.product(t, lst)))
    out.extend(t)
print(out)

['1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.2.4', '1.2.5', '1.3.4', '1.3.5']

# for the input my_list = [[1,2],3,[4,5]]
my_list = [[1,2],3,[4,5]]
print(out)
['1', '2', '1.3', '2.3', '1.3.4', '1.3.5', '2.3.4', '2.3.5']
```

Comment: This will not work if 1st item itself is a sub list

example : my_list=[[1,2],3,[4,5]]

Comment: What is the expected output for this input?

Comment: basically every combinations of all items.

expected output will be ['1.3.4' , '1.3.5' , '1.3' , '1' , '2.3.4' , '2.3.5' , '2.3' , '2']

Comment: First of all, the output I get for the input you stated in comment is the same as you expect except for the order. See updated answer for output for second input. Secondly, you need to make it clear in the problem statement and also honestly your attempt at it.